# How to migrate PicketBox LdapLoginModule to Elytron?

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, java-ee-8, wildfly-26

This is my old code for ldap connection

This creates a javax loginModule with name "login" so when a request came through JMS, our application looks for a javax LoginContext with name "login" and calls login() with login context and a callbackhandler that handles the username/password. The username and password is provided by the message from user/GUI.

```
<security-domain name="login" cache-type="default">     
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" flag="required">
           <module-option name="java.naming.provider.url" value="${java.naming.provider.url}"/>
           <module-option name="principalDNPrefix" value="${principalDNPrefix}"/>
           <module-option name="principalDNSuffix" value="${principalDNSuffix}"/>
           <module-option name="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="${ldap.connect.timeout}"/>
        </login-module>
     </authentication>
 </security-domain>
```

Here is my effort for translating it into elytron:
Security realms:

```
<security-realms>
   <ldap-realm name="ldapRealm" dir-context="ldapDirContext" direct-verification="true" allow-blank-password="true">
        <identity-mapping rdn-identifier="uid" search-base-dn="ou=company,dc=compauth,dc=comp,dc=de" />
    </ldap-realm>

    <caching-realm  name="cached-ldap" realm="ldapRealm"/>
 </security-realms>
```

Dir context

```
<dir-contexts>
    <dir-context name="ldapDirContext" url="${java.naming.provider.url}" authentication-level="none">
        <properties>
            <property name="com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.timeout" value="${ldap.connect.timeout}"/>
         </properties>
    </dir-context>
</dir-contexts>
```

Security domain:

```
<security-domains>
    <security-domain name="login" default-realm="cached-ldap" permission-mapper="default-permission-mapper">
        <realm name="cached-ldap" role-decoder="groups-to-roles"/>
   </security-domain>
</security-domains>
```

I'm getting error: No LoginModules configured for "login".

```
WARN [org.security.login.LoginServiceAbstract] (loginJmsContainer-2) LoginServiceBean.login exception occured : javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModules configured for login
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.init(LoginContext.java:264)
        at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.<init>(LoginContext.java:417)
        at gts.common.refdata.core.platform.security.login.LoginServiceAbstract.login(LoginServiceAbstract.java:83)
        at gts.common.refdata.core.platform.security.login.LoginServiceAbstract.login(LoginServiceAbstract.java:68)
        ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way how it works is not applicable with Elytron. There are no login modules that elytron creates that can be used in runtime. So It is easier to have a custom ldap implementation that does not depend on Elytron.